# I'm playing minecraft and I seem to lag out of the server every couple minutes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hosting

I haven't played minecraft in a couple months, a couple days ago my friends wanted to play so I joined their private server and I've been having this problem.

Its not just on their server, it does the same thing on all servers. I will be playing with normal frame rates and good game play until everything goes unresponsive, mobs stop moving, blocks don't drop when they break. And then I lag out of the server.

I have tried with and without Optifine, and with different resource packs. I'm playing on version 1.8.3 but it still does it in others. The error I get when I lag out is:

```
Internal Exception: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Comment: Try to ping the remote server using the `cmd`. If there is always a timeout (on many different servers) it might be that your ISP has some issues or maybe your router or even your network interface. You can recheck each of the named components one by one to fiddle out which one might be wrong or broken. Do you expect some issues like that while surfing or in other MP games?

Comment: Do you have other transfer services (like a crashplan backup, or bittorrent seeding) going through your connection? Heavy outbound traffic can cause this, especially if you have a smaller pipe. (My outbound used to be 1Mb/s max, so I felt this a lot.)

Comment: I don't know what any of this means or how to do any of those things. Is there a translation for noobs?

Comment: Ionic means this: Press `Windows Key + R`, type in `cmd`. A black window should open. type `ping <server IP>`, but replace `<server IP>` with the actual IP.  Tim S. was just asking if your internet was being used by anything else (like downloading a game or large file at a high speed), because if your internet is being used heavily, you could lose connection to the server momentarily and get disconnected.

Answer (score -1):

An easy fix: I suffered from this for 8 months. Run Minecraft as administrator. If that doesn't work, as the owner to run the server as an admin.

Comment: Please make your answer more detailed, so the questioner and others with this issue can easily understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

I moved away from using the minecraft_server*.exe file to the Java launched server and this problem disappeared.

Comment: I believe he's having issues with client and not running a server.